# How to make mtd-utils 2.0 for specified deployment path

Tags: linux, makefile

I downloaded mtd-utils 2.0 and I want to built it for specified deployment path. If I launch:

```
./configure --bindir .../mtd-utils-81049e5/deploy/usr/sbin
```

and then I do:

```
make
```

I will get output into folder, where I launched make. I want to have executable files somewhere like: bla/mtd-utils-2.0.../deploy/usr/sbin...

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this like that:

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/mtd-utils
make
make install
```

Finally, you get this:

```
$ tree /tmp/mtd-utils
/tmp/mtd-utils
├── sbin
│   ├── doc_loadbios
│   ├── docfdisk
│   ├── flash_erase
│   ├── flash_eraseall
│   ├── flash_lock
│   ├── flash_otp_dump
│   ├── flash_otp_info
│   ├── flash_otp_lock
│   ├── flash_otp_write
│   ├── flash_unlock
│   ├── flashcp
│   ├── ftl_check
│   ├── ftl_format
│   ├── jffs2dump
│   ├── jffs2reader
│   ├── mkfs.jffs2
│   ├── mkfs.ubifs
│   ├── mtd_debug
│   ├── mtdinfo
│   ├── mtdpart
│   ├── nanddump
│   ├── nandtest
│   ├── nandwrite
│   ├── nftl_format
│   ├── nftldump
│   ├── recv_image
│   ├── rfddump
│   ├── rfdformat
│   ├── serve_image
│   ├── sumtool
│   ├── ubiattach
│   ├── ubiblock
│   ├── ubicrc32
│   ├── ubidetach
│   ├── ubiformat
│   ├── ubimkvol
│   ├── ubinfo
│   ├── ubinize
│   ├── ubirename
│   ├── ubirmvol
│   ├── ubirsvol
│   └── ubiupdatevol
└── share
    └── man
        ├── man1
        │   └── mkfs.jffs2.1
        └── man8
            └── ubinize.8

5 directories, 44 files
```

Comment: No, I cannot use make install, because I need to deploy it on specified ARM processor with specific build system. I need to have makefile, which will do this thing.

Comment: You *can* use `make install` even if you cross compile, that's how some packages are built on some systems. Notice that you do not modify your system `/usr/bin` or `/sbin` directories, you install everything to `/tmp`.

Comment: Generally, if you cross compile it should be something like `./configure --host=aarch64-linux  --prefix=/tmp/path`

Comment: i cannot use --host option in my build system